# How do I match strings in shell-style using Perl?

Tags: perl

How to match strings in shell-style in Perl? For instance:

```
foo*
{bar,baz}.smth
joe?
foobar[0-9]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Your examples would be:

`/foo.*(bar|baz)\.smth joe/`

`/foobar\d/`

However, if what you actually wanted was shell-like **filename expansion** (e.g. the above was in context of `ls foobar[0-9]` ), use [`glob()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function:

`my @files = glob("foo* {bar,baz}.smth joe");`

`my @foobar_files = glob("foobar[0-9]");`

Please note that the syntax of regular expressions in Perl is [NOT that of filename expansion language](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html#DESCRIPTION)

Answer (score 0):

[`File::FnMatch`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::FnMatch) exposes your system's `fnmatch(3)` implementation, which is probably what implements the shell's wildcard patterns for you.

(Note that `{bar,baz}.smth` is not matching *per se*, it is simply "brace expansion" of strings.)